# Listener when user picks a date using MaterialDateTimePicker

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-datepicker

I'm currently using [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#additional-options) library for date picking, 
and I'm trying to listen when the user select day from the calendar to open another list depends on the day the user selected.

I have used  `dpd.setOnDateSetListener` and public void `onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)`. However, both of them are getting triggered only when the user clicks on the OK button and it doesn't trigger right away when the user selects the date.

Is there a way to be able to know when the user selects date?

In the screenshot below, you can see all days in this month are disabled even though the disabled day is selected and if the user clicks OK, it will be enabled. So what I'm trying to do is one of those 3 things:

1. Disable the OK button if the current day is disabled
2. Or, remove the auto select day once the calendar is opened so the user has no date selected means OK button won't get any data.
3. Or, set the auto select day to be the first enabled day on the calendar.

My problem right now that if the user hit ok even the auto selected day is a disabled day it will pop up to display the available times in that day for ex-mp Wednesday (from 10 to 15)

[image: Screenshot]

My Current code to set enabled days and disabled days :

```
Calendar day;
List<Calendar> weekends = new ArrayList<>();
int weeks = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < (weeks * 7); i = i + 7) {

    for (int d = 0; d < slots.getResponse().getDays().size(); d++) {

        day = Calendar.getInstance();
        switch (slots.getResponse().getDays().get(d).getDay()) {
            case "Sunday":
                day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.SUNDAY - day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + i));
                weekends.add(day);
                break;
            case "Monday":
                day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.MONDAY - day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + i));
                weekends.add(day);
                break;
            case "Tuesday":
                day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.TUESDAY - day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + i));
                weekends.add(day);
                break;
            case "Wednesday":
                day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.WEDNESDAY - day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + i));
                weekends.add(day);
                break;
            case "Thursday":
                day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.THURSDAY - day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + i));
                weekends.add(day);
                break;
            case "Friday":
                day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.FRIDAY - day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + i));
                weekends.add(day);
                break;
            case "Saturday":
                day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (Calendar.SATURDAY - day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + i));
                weekends.add(day);
                break;
        }
    }
}

Calendar[] SelectableDays = weekends.toArray(new Calendar[weekends.size()]);
dpd.setSelectableDays(SelectableDays);

Calendar minday = Calendar.getInstance();
minday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, minday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1);
dpd.setMinDate(minday);

/*
Disable Upcoming Daysa
 */

Calendar UpcomingDay;
boolean FirstLoop = true;
List<Calendar> nextDaysList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < slots.getResponse().getExecTime() - 1; i++) {
    UpcomingDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (FirstLoop) {
        UpcomingDay.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);
        i--;
        FirstLoop = false;
    } else {
        UpcomingDay.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i + 1);
    }
    nextDaysList.add(UpcomingDay);
}

Calendar[] DisabledDays = nextDaysList.toArray(new Calendar[nextDaysList.size()]);
dpd.setDisabledDays(DisabledDays);
```

Comment: Do you want trigger ok button when user click on any date?

Comment: ya that could work too as long as the selected day is enabled, Check my edited question

Comment: Do you use grable or manual put code from lib in your project?

Comment: You should be customise lib so you want put all lib. code in your project.

Comment: You should be do check date is validation in notifyOnDateListener() method 

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/wdullaer/materialdatetimepicker/date/DatePickerDialog.java

Comment: seems like only method i have is onDateSet, im using version 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.2'

Comment: there is a method in library `registerOnDateChangedListener` try using this

Comment: can you link example please ? and which  library version is this because i cant find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround that has a direct API provided by the library which is [`setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)`](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#datepickerdialog-setselectabledayscalendar-days). This takes an array of days as the parameter and enables you to enable the days only which you want to have enabled.

Hence, instead of disabling the dates, you may consider enabling it.

While setting up your `DatePickerDialog`, you may consider having the first enabled date as default as well, which might solve your problem as well. Initialize with the value that is your first enabled day.

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
  MainActivity.this,
  enabledYear, // Initial enabled year selection
  enabledMonth, // Initial enabled month selection
  enabledDayOfMonth // Inital enabled day selection
);
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, about first part im already using this method selectabledays  as you can see from my code above, however i believe the code the you linked that set first enabled date as default is what im looking for, but how do i get the first enabled day from my dynamic code

Comment: I see you are storing the enabled days in `SelectableDays`, and if the days are sorted there, you can just use the first element from the list to initialize the `dpd` in your case.